# Baofeng UV-9 Info and Help Please!

Tags: baofeng

I have scoured the internet for info on this radio. Specs, programming, manuals, to be exact, yet I can find NOTHING other than sellers of the radio. Anyone have any links they'd be able to share!  I appreciate the help

Comment: There's multiple models that start with "UV-9", but no "UV-9" itself: UV-9R, UV-9R PLUS, UV-9R ERA, UV-9S, UV-9X+, UV-920: So, using the full product name when searching might really help.

Comment: Hi Bruce, and welcome to the site!  I see you've been lurking for quite a while ;)

Comment: I see what you mean, there's nothing on [Baofeng's site](https://baofengtech.com/), [miklor.com](https://www.miklor.com/), or the [CHIRP site](https://chirp.danplanet.com/).  I read that CHIRP can be used if you set the model to "UV-82WP", but if that were true then CHIRP would have a selection for the UV-9 models and internally it would use the UV-82WP settings, so I don't believe it.  Personally I wouldn't buy an HT that isn't officially supported by CHIRP.  If you're thinking about buying one I'd advise against it, and if you have one then I'm sorry to hear it.

Comment: @ChrisK8NVH would be cool to say which setting you had to use in CHIRP to support that model. Even more awesome would be to let the CHIRP developers know, so that they put that info on their list of supported models.

Comment: @MarcusMüller CHIRP daily-20200227:  Setting is "UV-9R".  A popup states "this is a beta driver" however I had no issues. This radio seems to function the same and have the same capabilities as my BF-F8HP.  However battery and battery charger are different.  UV-9R is a little bigger than F8HP and is water resistant, thus needing a special CHIRP interface cable.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I just realized my earlier comment is wrong.  The plate on my radio says "UV-9R" not "UV-9".  I am deleting that comment now.

Answer (score 2):

I found a [user manual](https://www.genkin.name/2017/11/baofeng-uv-9r-users-manual/) online for the "Baofeng UV-9R". (backup on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20200814231842/https://www.genkin.name/2017/11/baofeng-uv-9r-users-manual/)).

Transmit is 5 W/1 W and the range for VHF is 136-174 MHz, UHF is 400-520 MHz. It also receives broadcast FM from 65-108 MHz.

It looks as if this is a standard Baofeng - meaning the instructions for the UV-5R or UV-82 will probably work as well.